# what is the different between Buffer Cache that displayed from free command VS the available memory

Tags: rhel, memory, cache, hadoop, free

we have 463 RHEL 7.6 machines in the cluster most of then are HDFS machines (  datanode )

from  `free -g` command we can that usually **buff/cach**e is around 30-50 when total memory is 256G

as I know - a buffer is an area of memory used to temporarily store data while being moved from one place to another

but the available memory is also memory that used for application

so I am little confused , what is the diff between **buff/cache**  to **available** memory ?

Comment: Same question essentially as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/709457/3976

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is disk caching is relevant after we disabled the swap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709457/is-disk-caching-is-relevant-after-we-disabled-the-swap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the buffers column in the output from free?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34422/what-is-the-buffers-column-in-the-output-from-free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Available** memory is the total amount of RAM available for applications.
 **buff/cache** is memory that Linux uses for disk caching; it is freed when applications require it, so it doesn't count as "used" memory.

Quoting from http://www.linuxatemyram.com (emphasis mine):

> Both you and Linux agree that memory taken by applications is "used", while memory that isn't used for anything is "free".
>
> But how do you count memory that is currently used for something, but can still be made available to applications?
>
> You might count that memory as "free" and/or "available". **Linux instead counts it as "used", but also "available".** (...)
> This "something" is (roughly) what top and free calls "buffers" and "cached". Since your and Linux's terminology differs, **you might think you are low on ram when you're not.**

See also:

- ["buff/cache" is very high, how I can free it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521488/buff-cache-is-very-high-how-i-can-free-it)
- [What is difference between cached memory and used memory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263764/what-is-difference-between-cached-memory-and-used-memory)